# use of class template requires template argument list link list

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to get a linked list, and here is my code
**node.h**

```
template<class Node_entry>
struct Node{
    Node_entry entry;
    Node<Node_entry> *next;

    Node();
    Node(Node_entry entry,Node<Node_entry>* add_on=NULL);
};

template<class Node_entry>
Node<Node_entry>::Node()
{
    next=NULL;
}

template<class Node_entry>
Node<Node_entry>::Node(Node_entry item,Node<Node_entry>* add_on)
{
    entry=item;
    next=add_on;
}
```

**Queue.h**

```
#include "node.h"

enum Error_code{
    success,overflow,underflow
};

template<class Queue_entry>
class Queue {
public:
    Queue();
    bool empty() const;
    Error_code append(const Queue_entry &item);
    Error_code serve();
    Error_code retrieve(Queue_entry &item)const;
    int size()const;
    //Safety features for linked structures
    ~Queue();
    Queue(const Queue<Queue_entry> &original);
    void operator = (const Queue<Queue_entry> &original);
protected:
    Node<Queue_entry> *front, *rear;
};
```

and then i got a problem in following code:

```
template<class Queue_entry>
Error_code Queue<Queue_entry>::append(const Queue_entry &item)
{
    Node<Queue_entry> *new_rear=new Node(item);
    if(new_rear==NULL) return overflow;
    if(rear==NULL) front=rear=new_rear;
    else{
        rear->next=new_rear;
        rear=new_rear;
    }
    return success;
}
```

The compiler turns out 
The code:

```
Node<Queue_entry> *new_rear=new Node(item);
```

error C2955: 'Node' : use of class template requires template argument list

Comment: Sounds pretty self-explanatory.  It's telling you forgot to supply a template argument list (i.e. something of the form `<...>`).

Comment: Thank you!  Could you tell me how can i change my code to make it runable? I have some problems in dong this .

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the template parameter in the second use of `Node`. The line in question should read

```
Node<Queue_entry> *new_rear=new Node<Queue_entry>(item);
```